# Problem validating django project no module named 'project name'

Tags: django

Unfortunately the traceback on this one hasn't been very enlightening so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

When I try to run syncdb, validate, or runserver I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute_manager
    setup_environ(settings_mod)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in setup_environ
    project_module = import_module(project_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named osps
```

Where osps is the name of my project.  The manage.py file hasn't been touched and looks to be the standard file django generates on creation of a project.  `osps` is referenced twice in my settings.py.  Once on the database name declaration as as `os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/osps.db'` and once in the standard `ROOT_URLCONF = 'OSPS.urls'`.

Additionally a quick project wide search doesn't turn up any `import osps` statements.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I had this problem once -- the issue turned out to be that I had renamed the directory. i.e. `OSPS.urls` works because the directory is named `OSPS` and considered a python module because of `__init__.py`

Comment: Its looking for a lower case `osps` module not an uppercase `OSPS`? i beleive in some pep it states that module names should be lower case. (also make sure you have a `__init__.py` file. I've deleted mine by mistake before.)

Comment: The __init__.py file is there and yes the project name os uppercase and the none existent module its lowercase.

Comment: @Daniel two things: 1) if you created this on windows and used something like winSCP it may have added a .bin to the filename.`__init__.py.bin` 2) it is looking for a lowercase version of it was there a time when you used the lowercase version?

Answer (score 4):

make sure your directories look like this.

```
-- osps\
 |-- app1\
 | `-- ...
 |-- __init__.py   <- makes this a module
 |-- manage.py
 |-- settings.py
 `-- urls.py
```

worst comes to worst, put this line at the top of settings.py:

```
import os.path.dirname as d, sys.path as p; p.insert(0,d(d(__file__)))
```

this will put your project's parent folder at the top of the import chain.
better though is to remove all references to your toplevel project. It should not be part of any references between apps anyway. This is best practice for pluggable/reusable apps.
in which case,

```
import os.path.dirname as _d, sys.path as _p; _p.insert(0,_d(__file__))
```